# Ubuntu 15.04 - enter black screen after installing the upgrade of software ( Nvidia GTX 860M )

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.04, graphics

Host: 15.04

Kernel version: 3.19.0-41-generic

Graphic card: Nvidia GTX 860M

Graphic card driver: 352.63 from nvidia-352-updates

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710MQ

I used Nouveau display driver before but switching to use nvidia driver because Nouveau sometimes hangs during the boot and that is very troublesome.

After changing the driver to nvidia, things went well until last night I apply the latest software updates from official Ubuntu. The system boots but it can not enter the xwindow, I can only use my linux in terminal mode.

I installed the Nvidia driver through "Software & Updates" ---> "Additional Drivers".

The only thing I can do is to purge all nvidia things by typing

`sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nvidia-*`

I reboot the laptop and it selected nouveau as its default graphic driver.

During the terminal mode when the system failed to launch xwindow, there are some messages related to nvidia.

```
[   12.524163] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   12.524166] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   12.526315] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   12.528986] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   12.528989] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  352.63  Sat Nov  7 21:25:42 PST 2015
```

I am not sure if this is the root cause and please let me know how should I get it work if you know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: anyone please? I think this is relatively critical.